# How to disable multiple select options

Tags: jquery, html-select

How to disable multiple options in one select. For example i have 2 selects with 5 and 3 options. So if i select 3rd option in second select, i want to disable 3rd,4th and 5th option in first select:

```
<select name="smjer">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Second select:

```
<select name="godina" >
<option value="1" >1.</option>
<option value="2" >2.</option>
<option value="3">3.</option>
</select>
```

I've tried removing options, but then I can't retrieve them without refreshing page:

```
var ary=[3,4,5];
$('[name=smjer] option').filter(function(){
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),ary) >-1);
}).remove();
```

Comment: Well, you're `.remove`ing them.  You didn't *expect* them to be gone?

Comment: use show/hide instead of remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just hide them :

```
var ary = [3, 4, 5];
$('[name=smjer] option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value), ary) > -1);
}).hide();
```

and when again required show it:

```
var ary = [3, 4, 5];
$('[name=smjer] option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value), ary) > -1);
}).show();
```

To make it even better, you can do this:

```
var ary = [3, 4, 5];

// Get the options to be hidden/shown
var $options = $('[name=smjer] option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value), ary) > -1);
});

// Hide the options
$options.hide();

// Show the options
$options.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can disable them:

```
var ary=[3,4,5];
$('[name=smjer] option').filter(function(){
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),ary) >-1);
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: `.disabled="disabled"` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  Try `.prop('disabled', true)` instead.  Course, then you still have to worry about reenabling them when the other select box's value changes...

Comment: @nnnnnn: All browsers that are worth a damn.  `disabled` is a standard attribute of `<option>` elements, and appears as a settable DOM property.  The references i'm seeing say all browsers support it.