# Disabling checkbox and dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am developing a calendar app for my website, and I am in a bit of a pickle. Here is the html for a part of the app I require help on:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="main b_width"><strong>Repeat Every:</strong></td>
<td class="main width">

<select name="Day">

<option value="1" selected>no recurrence</option>
<option value="2">days</option>
<option value="3">weeks</option>
<option value="4">month by day</option>
<option value="5">month by week</option>

</select>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="main b_width"><strong>At Days:</strong></td>
<td class="main b_width">

<select name="Day">

    <option value="1" selected>First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>

</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="Monday" ;>&nbsp;Mon&nbsp;

 </td>
</tr>
```

What i want to know is, the first select box that is created, for the first option 'no recurrence', how would I make all the other select boxes and check boxes inactive, disabling them so no data can be selected, Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable multiple select options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069204/how-to-disable-multiple-select-options)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select[name=Day]').eq(0).change(function () {
    $('select[name=Day]').eq(1).prop('disabled', (this.value === '1'));
    $('input[name=Monday]').prop('disabled', (this.value === '1'));
}).change();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bAah4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table :input:gt(0)').prop('disabled', true);
$('#recur').change(function () {
    $('table :input:gt(0)').prop('disabled', ($(this).val() == 1));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BdBfH/1/)**

One problem with your example though is that you have multiple select elements with the same name. I updated your HTML to give them unique IDs. See the fiddle for the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$("#Day").change(function(e){
        if($(this).val()=='1'){
            $("#Day2").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: a) There's no element with the ID of "Day" (`$("#Day")`) and b) how do you propose not disabling the other inputs should the user change the drop down again?

Comment: Is just a example, dont resolve the problem, but show the way.

Comment: So you're saying your answer is just an example and not really an answer? Not to mention that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to acheive this.
Add the id `recurrence` to your first select box and the class `recurrence-input` to every element that you want to be disabled when no recurrence is chosen and use the following javascript (using jquery):

```
$('#recurrence').on('change', function() {} {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
        $('.recurrence-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.recurrence-input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

if `no-recurrence` is the default value for your select box then you should make the other inputs disabled when the document is loaded as well.